# Nodejs app on Apache reverse proxy crash after a while (error 503)

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy

I have an nodejs application running on a VPS like this with pm2 :

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');

const privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('./privkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('./fullchain.pem', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())


require("./routes/wordpress.routes.js")(app);
require("./routes/entries.routes.js")(app);

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(8080);
httpsServer.listen(8443);
```

And the reverse proxy is configured like that (almost the same for https) :

```
ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full
    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>
  ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8080/"
  ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8080/"
<Directory /home/example/domains/api.example.com/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/example/domains/api.example.com/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

It works perfectly but... After an indeterminate time, when accessing to api.example.com, I got a 503 error, and pm2 says that my application is stopped. `pm2 logs` doesn't give me anything. The only log I have is from apache :

```
[Tue Sep 07 02:38:03.207929 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 16998] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[Tue Sep 07 02:38:03.207975 2021] [proxy_http:error] [pid 16998] [client 172.70.82.111:56154] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
[Tue Sep 07 02:38:04.018152 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 2698] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[Tue Sep 07 02:38:04.018178 2021] [proxy_http:error] [pid 2698] [client 172.70.82.163:36668] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost, referer: http://api.example.com/orders
```

What happens ? I don't have anything to understand it... When i do a `pm2 restart` it works again, but I have to do it manually, I don't know why pm2 doesn't do it himself...

Comment: Hi Have you found what the problem was? I have similar situation